# Installing Rubymine without sun-java6-jre

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, java

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and am looking to install Rubymine. It seems every tutorial recommends installing `sun-java6-jre` before downloading `rubymine` but `aptitude` and `apt-get` are returning nothing, claiming that `sun-java6-jre` no longer exists.

I'm completely unfamiliar with how to handle tar files and am unfamiliar with what to do once I start extracting files from the download.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Sun Java 6 packages are available from the "partner" repositories,
which you can enable by adding the following lines to
`/etc/apt/sources.list`, and then running `sudo apt-get update`:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
```

After adding the "partner" repositories, you will be able to install
the `sun-java6-jre` package the usual way (Ubuntu Software Center,
Synaptic, `apt-get`, whatever).

Alternatively, you can try installing `openjdk-6-jre` instead, which
is entirely free software and is thus available from the main
repositories:

```
apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

Information on Java support for Ubuntu is available at: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Comment: Okay. Seems like promising advice, but at the end of the apt-get update I get this error E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: Nevermind. I had to close synaptic package manager. This worked beautifully thank you.